# Cannot connect to Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Oracle Developer is not connecting. Please help.
My username and password are scott.

[image]

Comment: You need to change the connection name to whatever you called your Oracle instance when you created it. As we have no idea what that might be, and don't have access to your computer to find out, we can't help you. Thanks for sharing your username and password, though.

Comment: Can you make sure your database is up and running? And do a `tnsping orcl` from command prompt

Comment: Is you oracle database and oracle sqldeveloper are in the same machine?

Comment: Since I can connect to DB using SQL Plus, it shows My db is running.

Comment: Yes my oracle database and oracle sqldeveloper are in the same machine.....

Comment: Ken..My connection name is ORCL. 

I fired select sys_context('userenv','instance_name') from dual;
AND IT SHOWS ME "orcl". 


BUT STILL IT'S NOT WORKING.

Comment: Can you post your tnsnames.ora file content?

Answer (score 1):

make sure your listener is running,you can try lsnrctl start